# Use of domain in search of One2many field in List view in Odoo-9

Tags: python, listview, odoo, odoo-9

i have One2many field **product_attributes** in **product.template** and **value** field in **product.attributes.custom**

```
class ProductTemplateCus(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    product_attributes = fields.One2many('product.attributes.custom','product_id')

class ProductAttributes(models.Model):
    _name = 'product.attributes.custom'
    value = fields.Char(string='Value')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template',string='Product')
```

Product 1 **product_attributes** contains 2 values:

```
value= 'color: red'
value= 'others: red'
```

product 2 **product_attributes** contains 2 values:

```
value= 'color: white'
value= 'others: red'
```

I did like below in search xml:

```
<field 
name="product_attributes" string="Color"
filter_domain="['&amp;',('product_attributes.value','ilike','color'),('product_attributes.value','ilike',self)]"
/>
```

So if **red** is searched, only product 1 containing both **color** and **red** should be shown. But I am unable to get result. I am getting both products.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `search_domain` means nothing here. You should use `domain` instead.

Comment: Now I know the difference between filter_domain and domain. I was unaware about that.
For solving my problem I used search function to get product ids which have selected attribute name and value only and included that in arguments in search function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few types of domain for field in the search view:

- `domain` - just like the domain on the field declaration in the python class, limits the records got from the database;
- `filter_domain` - overrides the `name_search` method which would normally have only `('name', 'ilike', self)`.

In your case, I believe, you need the `filter_domain`.

---

Just a suggestion, you could add the `:` after the attribute name to differentiate between the attribute and its value, given that you use the same convention for all your attributes: 
`('product_attributes.value', 'ilike', 'color: ')`

The default operator between domains is `&` and in this case can be omitted.

Comment: I solved it using search function. Now I know the difference between filter_domain and domain. .

Answer (score 0):

For solving my problem I used search function to get product ids which have selected attribute name and value only and included that in arguments in search function as

```
args += [['id', 'in', productids]]
```

I don't know if it was a right approach to do it. But it solved my problem.